# Can I get the full path of native artifacts that Rust links against?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm using the 32-bit version of Rust 1.6 on Windows 10 to compile [rustlab](https://github.com/smitec/rustlab). When I run `cargo build` to build it, it says to

> link against the following native artifacts when linking against this static library

I would like to do exactly that. Is there a way to get the full paths for the libraries that were used?

```bsh
PS C:\rs\rustlab> cargo build -v
   Compiling libc v0.2.7
     Running `rustc C:\Users\cameron\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-48ad6e4054423464\libc-0.2.7\src\lib.rs --crate-name libc --crate-typ
e lib -g --cfg "feature=\"default\"" -C metadata=0c94fdfb80c4b805 -C extra-filename=-0c94fdfb80c4b805 --out-dir C:\rs\rustlab\target\deb
ug\deps --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=C:\rs\rustlab\target\debug\deps -L dependency=C:\rs\rustlab\target\debug\deps --cap-lints all
ow`
   Compiling rustlab v0.1.0 (file:///C:/rs/rustlab)
     Running `rustc src\lib.rs --crate-name rustlab --crate-type staticlib --crate-type dylib -g --out-dir C:\rs\rustlab\target\debug --
emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=C:\rs\rustlab\target\debug -L dependency=C:\rs\rustlab\target\debug\deps --extern libc=C:\rs\rustlab\ta
rget\debug\deps\liblibc-0c94fdfb80c4b805.rlib`
note: link against the following native artifacts when linking against this static library
note: the order and any duplication can be significant on some platforms, and so may need to be preserved
note: library: gcc_eh
note: library: gcc_eh
note: library: ws2_32
note: library: userenv
note: library: shell32
note: library: advapi32
```

For example, I have three `x86` versions of `WS2_32.lib`. Which one was used?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86\WS2_32.Lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x86\WS2_32.Lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x86\WS2_32.Lib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There are two ABI options for Rust on Windows](https://www.rust-lang.org/downloads.html): MSVC and GNU (GCC). You say you're using the 32-bit version of Rust 1.6; there's no 32-bit version using the MSVC ABI for Rust 1.6 (it's only available starting with Rust 1.8), so I assume you're using the GNU ABI version.

If you are indeed using the GNU ABI version, then you need to link against GNU ABI static libraries. These libraries have names like `libXXXX.a`, instead of `XXXX.lib` for MSVC.

If you don't have a file named `libws2_32.a` anywhere on your system, then you need to install MinGW, which is a port of GCC for Windows that also includes static libraries for the most commonly used Windows DLLs. There are multiple active "forks" of MinGW: [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/) and [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) have more recent versions of GCC than the original [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) project, which appears to be dormant.

> Is there a way to get the full paths for the libraries that were used?

Normally, you don't specify the full path when linking. For GCC, you pass an option like `-lws2_32` and the linker will find the library for you. If the linker doesn't find it, you can add an `-L <path>` option to add a directory in the linker's search path for static libraries.

Cargo has some documentation on how to write a [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) that can add these options automatically when you run `cargo build`.

Comment: You guessed right. I am using the GNU 32-bit version of Rust in order to build libraries for GNU Octave. I see that Rust has a `libws2_32.a` and so does Octave. How do I know if they are compatible? Can I have Rust use the one from Octave? The locations are `C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust stable GNU 1.6\lib\rustlib\i686-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libws2_32.a` and `C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\lib\libws2_32.a`. If I created a build script that outputed `rustc-link-search` to the Octave path, would it use `libws2_32.a` from there instead?

Comment: *How do I know if they are compatible?* Try them both! Seriously, I think they should both work, as long as they define the symbols your application and its dependencies need. If linking with Octave's `libws2_32.a` doesn't work, you'll have trouble linking with Octave's other libraries! *... would it use `libws2_32.a` from there instead?* I think so. One way to be sure is to use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to watch for events on files with that name.